# Pass state data between component through navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

my issue is look so simple but I can't figure is out how to solve it
I have two component that I navigate to them by using StackNavigator,
in one of the component I have state with values, I need to pass the state  values to the other component, but as I said I using StackNavigator to go from one component to the other, I trying to figure out how can I do so

my navigator:

```
 const Navigate = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Riddles: { screen: RiddlesScreen },
    Introduction: { screen: IntroductionScreen },
    About: { screen: AboutScreen },
  },
  { headerMode: 'screen' }
);
```

My homescreen class:

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Home navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

my riddlescreen class:

```
class RiddlesScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Riddles navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

in the Riddles component (at the RiddleScreen class) I have state with the values that I need to pass to Home component (at HomeScreen class).

what is the best way to achieve this goal?
every help really appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data between screens while navigating. More info [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#state-The-screen's-current-stateroute).

**Example**

```
<Button onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('SomeScreen', { some: this.state.someValue})}} />

// and in SomeScreen
console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.some);
```

Comment: ok, look good. On the SomeScreen how can I update the "some" value in the FirstScreen?

Comment: @gaidediz take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46879736/2315280)

Comment: from the child component I need to update the state at the parent component, in my case Home is the parent and Riddle is the child,,, the fist screen that the navigator navigate to is Home.. at home we have button that onPress pass you to riddles component via navigator, at riddle component I have some state and I want that the home component gets update about that state... what I need to do to achieve that?

Comment: @gaidediz pass the function that updates state in Home component to Riddle component as a param like `some` param

Comment: Great it works!!! thanks! I done the follow: this.props.navigation.state.params.some(this.state.count) on child component and on parent  this.props.navigation.navigate('Riddles', { some: this.onChangeCount.bind(this)}). if I set the this.props.navigation.state.params.some(this.state.count) under render it popup an error Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition ... but can be moved to `componentWillMount`, so I tried under componentWillMount but it doesn't update the parent... do you now some workaroud?